# Ruby Imap / mail excluding specific files

Tags: ruby, email, imap

My code gets all attachments from an email and checks the file extension before downloading it. So far I have excluded every file that is a picture, so .PNG and .JPG files.

```
mail.attachments.each do |attachment|
 next unless File.extname(attachment.filename).match(ACCEPTED_FILE_EXTENSIONS)

 File.open("../files/#{attachment.filename}", 'wb') do |file|
   file.write(attachment.body.decoded)
 end
end
```

The problem with this is that, if I want to download .JPG and .PNG files then every file in the email that is a picture, will be downloaded. So if someone sends me an email and has some custom made footer with an ad for some toothbrush, then the picture of the toothbrush will also be downloaded, even tho I don't want it. I only want the attachments that were selected as "attach a file", when you choose the files that you actually want to send someone, if it makes sense.

so my question is. Is there a way to exclude these "random" pictures?

Comment: You can look at the content-disposition, which is often "attachment" for attachments. But sometimes it's not specified, and sometimes humans send images by including them in HTML messages, in which case they're technically not attachments. You might want to use a composite test, where you use a size test (> 50k?) and the value of the content-disposition.

Comment: If have the provision to change the filename/ file-content when the user uploads it, you can filter out irrelevant images. Maybe simple symmetric encryption of filename/content is enough.

Comment: Unless you're doing some server-side parsing, there's no way to determine the actual contents of a binary blob before it's been downloaded. Sometimes emails will contain a recommended filename or MIME encoding, but sometimes you'll have to check the actual magic numbers with a utility like `file` to determine it. So, your question isn't really answerable as currently written.